# I try move one page other page in react native but routes.js getting issue

Tags: android, react-native

I can try to add react-native-router-flux in the react-native project but getting an error while run project please blew screenshot.[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vL8.png)

[image]

```
{
"name": "AsseProject",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.2",
"react-native": "^0.61.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.8.4",
"@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"eslint": "6.8.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please add your package.json file here

Comment: done package file please check

Comment: Did you install the react-native-router-flux using npm ? But your dependencies doesn't have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario I think you have not install the native dependencies in order to work with router flux.

**SOLUTION**

- Install native dependencies used by React Native Router - [Link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/getting-started.html)

Since the v4.2.0-beta.x is based on React Navigation v4.x you need to install react-navigation v4.x native dependencies before install router flux.

**Install navigation using this**

```
npm install react-navigation
```

**After that run this code and install other dependencies**

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

**Finally you can install router flux using this command**

```
npm install --save react-native-router-flux
```

- Clean your project and run the project using react-native run-android / react-native run-ios

**NOTE : If you are using react-navigation V5.x you will not be able to use router flux. Therefore make sure you have installed react-navigation v4.x**